# Glossaries for acronyms and symbols: page references for acronyms and equation references for symbols

Tags: glossaries

I'd like to use the `glossaries` package for both acronyms and symbols, showing page references for the acronyms and equation references for the symbols.

I know that the `counter` package option can be set to `equation` with
`\usepackage[counter=equation]{glossaries}`, however, then the acronyms glossary shows number of equations which are dead links.

I modified a sample file from CTAN (`sampleSort.tex`) to provide a minimal working example.

```
% This file is public domain
% If you want to use arara, you need the following directives:
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
\documentclass{report}

% If you want to add babel to this document, you may have to
% replace the : character in the labels if you are using a
% language setting (e.g. french) that makes : active.

\usepackage[plainpages=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronym,counter=equation]{glossaries}

% Define a new glossary type called notation
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}

\makeglossaries

\newcounter{sortcount}

\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
  \ifdefstring{#2}{notation}%
  {%
     \stepcounter{sortcount}%
     \edef#1{\glssortnumberfmt{\arabic{sortcount}}}%
  }%
  {%
     \glsdosanitizesort
  }%
}

 % Notation definitions

\newglossaryentry{not:set}{type=notation, % glossary type
name={$\mathcal{S}$},
text={\mathcal{S}},
description={A set}}

\newglossaryentry{not:emptyset}{type=notation,
name={$\emptyset$},
text={\emptyset},
description={The empty set}}


\newglossaryentry{not:card}{type=notation,
name={$|\mathcal{S}|$},    
vtext={|\mathcal{S}|},
description={cardinality of $\mathcal{S}$}}



% Added variables
\newglossaryentry{not:a}{type=notation,
name={\ensuremath{a}},
text={a},
description={a variable}}

\newglossaryentry{not:b}{type=notation,
name={\ensuremath{b}},
text={b},
description={another variable}}


% Main glossary definitions

\newglossaryentry{gls:set}{name=set,description={A collection of distinct objects}}

\newglossaryentry{gls:card}{name=cardinality,description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

 % Acronym definitions

\newacronym{zfc}{ZFC}{Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory}
\newacronym{ad}{AD}{axiom of determinacy}
\newacronym{nf}{NF}{new foundations}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Document using the glossaries Package}
\author{Nicola Talbot}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
 %stop hyperref complaining about duplicate page identifiers:
\pagenumbering{Alph}
This is a sample document illustrating the use of the
\textsf{glossaries} package.  In this example, a new glossary type
called \texttt{notation} is defined, so that the document can have a
separate glossary of terms, list of acronyms and index of notation.
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\Glspl{gls:set} are denoted by a calligraphic font
e.g.\ $\gls{not:set}$.

The \gls{gls:card} of a set $\mathcal{S}$ is denoted
$\gls{not:card}$. The empty set is denoted
$\gls{not:emptyset}$.

Here are some acronyms: \gls{nf}, \gls{zfc} and \gls{ad}.

\chapter{Another Chapter}

Another mention of the empty set $\gls{not:emptyset}$.

Here are the acronyms again: \gls{nf}, \gls{zfc} and \gls{ad}.

\begin{equation}
    \gls{not:a} = \gls{not:b}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your terms for a particular glossary are always used in a numbered maths environment, then you can set the counter in the final optional argument of `\newglossary`:

```
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}[equation]
```

All your terms in the other glossaries will use the default counter (`page` or the value of the `counter` package option).

If your symbols are mixed in numbered and non-numbered maths environments (for example, `\begin{equation}\gls{not:a}\end{equation}` and `$\gls{not:a}$`) then you need to use the `counter=equation` option in the numbered maths environments:

```
\begin{equation}
    \gls[counter=equation]{not:a} = \gls[counter=equation]{not:b}
\end{equation}
```

If you try this modification with the MWE in your question, you'll find warnings like:

```
Package glossaries Warning: Hyper target `2.0.1' can't be formed by prefixing
location `2.1'. You need to modify the definition of \theHequation
otherwise you will get the warning: "`name{equation.2.1}' has been
 referenced but does not exist"
```

This means you need to redefine `\theHequation` so that it's in the form *prefix*`.\theequation` or just make it the same as `\theequation`. This is a limitation imposed by the way the `glossaries` package tries to reconstruct the hyperlinks in the number list given the counter name, prefix and the indexed value.

In this example, `\theequation` is formed from the chapter number and the value of the `equation` counter, which should typically form unique target names, so `\theHequation` can simply be redefined to `\theequation`.

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[plainpages=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc,acronym]{glossaries}

% Define a new glossary type called notation
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}

\renewcommand\theHequation{\theequation}

\makeglossaries

\newcounter{sortcount}

\renewcommand{\glsprestandardsort}[3]{%
  \ifdefstring{#2}{notation}%
  {%
     \stepcounter{sortcount}%
     \edef#1{\glssortnumberfmt{\arabic{sortcount}}}%
  }%
  {%
     \glsdosanitizesort
  }%
}

 % Notation definitions

\newglossaryentry{not:set}{type=notation, % glossary type
name={$\mathcal{S}$},
text={\mathcal{S}},
description={A set}}

\newglossaryentry{not:emptyset}{type=notation,
name={$\emptyset$},
text={\emptyset},
description={The empty set}}


\newglossaryentry{not:card}{type=notation,
name={$|\mathcal{S}|$},    
text={|\mathcal{S}|},
description={cardinality of $\mathcal{S}$}}



% Added variables
\newglossaryentry{not:a}{type=notation,
name={\ensuremath{a}},
text={a},
description={a variable}}

\newglossaryentry{not:b}{type=notation,
name={\ensuremath{b}},
text={b},
description={another variable}}


% Main glossary definitions

\newglossaryentry{gls:set}{name=set,description={A collection of distinct objects}}

\newglossaryentry{gls:card}{name=cardinality,description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

 % Acronym definitions

\newacronym{zfc}{ZFC}{Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory}
\newacronym{ad}{AD}{axiom of determinacy}
\newacronym{nf}{NF}{new foundations}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Document using the glossaries Package}
\author{Nicola Talbot}
\pagenumbering{alph}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
%stop hyperref complaining about duplicate page identifiers:
\pagenumbering{Alph}
This is a sample document illustrating the use of the
\textsf{glossaries} package.  In this example, a new glossary type
called \texttt{notation} is defined, so that the document can have a
separate glossary of terms, list of acronyms and index of notation.
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents

\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\Glspl{gls:set} are denoted by a calligraphic font
e.g.\ $\gls{not:set}$.

The \gls{gls:card} of a set $\mathcal{S}$ is denoted
$\gls{not:card}$. The empty set is denoted
$\gls{not:emptyset}$.

Here are some acronyms: \gls{nf}, \gls{zfc} and \gls{ad}.

\chapter{Another Chapter}

Another mention of the empty set $\gls{not:emptyset}$.

Here are the acronyms again: \gls{nf}, \gls{zfc} and \gls{ad}.

\begin{equation}
    \gls[counter=equation]{not:a} = \gls[counter=equation]{not:b}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort providing this package along with all the documentation and help here at stackexchange and all the other forums!